# Page number "1/3" in C7 that repeats top of each page in a sheet, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, page-numbering

I have a workbook with several sheets. On every sheet i repet row 1 to 13 on each page. In cell C7 i want page number and total number of pages in the format of "1/3".

I have found this VBA code to do part of the problem

placed this part in a module

```
Sub PageNumber(MyRange As String)
Dim iVPC As Integer
Dim iHPC As Integer
Dim iVPB As VPageBreak
Dim iHPB As HPageBreak
Dim iNumPage As Integer
iHPC = 1
iVPC = 1
If ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Order = xlDownThenOver Then
    iHPC = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1
Else
    iVPC = ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1
End If
iNumPage = 1
For Each iVPB In ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks
    If iVPB.Location.Column > ActiveCell.Column Then Exit For
    iNumPage = iNumPage + iHPC
Next
For Each iHPB In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
    If iHPB.Location.Row > ActiveCell.Row Then Exit For
    iNumPage = iNumPage + iVPC
Next
MyRange = "'" & iNumPage & "/" & Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")

End Sub
```

placed this part in the sheet object window

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim StrString As String
    Call PageNumber(StrString)
    Range("C7:C7").Value = StrString
End Sub
```

The part i have problems with is that i need iNumPage (the current page number, not the total number of pages)to update for every page that is going in to  print.
Is there a way maybe piggyback riding of the page number function from header and footer, and using it in Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint or is there another solution. The page number is only for cell C7 because of the repet of row 1-13 on top of each page in print out.

Comment: I've asked this question on another site and this was as close we could get, but it's not a good solution because of the handling of print property's, the documents prints once for each page and that will cause trouble if you what print on both sides or in a pdf file.
`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked this question on another site and this was as close we could get, but it's not a good solution because of the handling of print property's, the documents prints once for each page and that will cause trouble if you what print on both sides or in a pdf file.

```
Sub Print_This_Sheet()
     Dim i, iTot_pages
     Dim lastrow As Long
     Dim LastColumn As Long
     Dim sht As Worksheet
     Set sht = ActiveSheet
     Dim LastColumStr As String

     lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     LastColumStr = getColLet(LastColumn)
     Application.EnableEvents = False                           ' no interference with workbook_BeforePrint !!!!

     With ActiveSheet
          .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:" & LastColumStr & lastrow
          .PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$13"
          MsgBox "and other pagesetup-setting ....", vbInformation
          iTot_pages = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")     '----> normally the number of pages

          For i = 1 To iTot_pages                               'loop through those pages
               .Range("C7").Value = "'" & i & "/" & iTot_pages     'before printing, ajust C7
               .PrintOut i, i, 1, True                          'PrintOut with previeuw page per page'print one page
          Next
     End With

     Application.EnableEvents = True                            'enable events again
End Sub


Public Function getColLet(colNum As Long) As String
Dim i As Long, x As Long
    'If Not isBetween(colNum, 1, Application.Columns.count) Then Exit Function
    For i = Int(Log(CDbl(25 * (CDbl(colNum) + 1))) / Log(26)) - 1 To 0 Step -1
        x = (26 ^ (i + 1) - 1) / 25 - 1
        If colNum > x Then getColLet = getColLet & Chr(((colNum - x - 1) \ 26 ^ i) Mod 26 + 65)
    Next i
End Function
```

Contributor to this solution mcranmoss, the function is from a previous project so it's from somewhere....